# Tkz-Graph only two of six vertices should be labeled

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-graph

This is the code to a graph I'm drawing, but I only want the vertices "a" and "e" to be labeled; the rest should just show as vertices without a label. How can I do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
        \SetUpVertex[FillColor=black, MinSize=8pt]
            \Vertex[Math,Lpos=180,x=0,y=-1]{a}
            \Vertex[Math,Lpos=90,x=1,y=0]{b} 
            \Vertex[Math,Lpos=270,x=1,y=-2]{c}
            \Vertex[Math,Lpos=90,x=3,y=0]{d}
            \Vertex[Math,Lpos=270,x=3,y=-2]{e}
            \Vertex[Math,x=4,y=-1]{f}
        \SetUpEdge[lw=1.5pt] 
            \Edges(a,b,c,d,e,f,d,b,e,c,a)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `NoLabel` to the vertices that shouldn't have a label. For those you can also remove `Math,LPos=..`, as those don't have any effect when there are no labels.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
        \SetUpVertex[FillColor=black, MinSize=8pt]
            \Vertex[Math,Lpos=180,x=0,y=-1]{a}
            \Vertex[x=1,y=0,NoLabel]{b} 
            \Vertex[x=1,y=-2,NoLabel]{c}
            \Vertex[x=3,y=0,NoLabel]{d}
            \Vertex[Math,Lpos=270,x=3,y=-2]{e}
            \Vertex[x=4,y=-1,NoLabel]{f}
        \SetUpEdge[lw=1.5pt] 
            \Edges(a,b,c,d,e,f,d,b,e,c,a)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Also, `Lpos` for those vertices with `NoLabel` can also be removed, as they have no effect anymore :-)

Comment: @hooy Indeed, good point. Will edit.